# texture on wrong side, normals are good

Tags: rendering, uv, normals

[image]

Ive created a procedural texture shown in the middle, and baked it to a texture, tried multiple uv mapping methods, reseting vectors and the baked texture always obeys the lighting of the face normals as id expect based on the blue normal face map. However when applying this texture to the model it displays about half it on the wrong side of my mesh.

Anything I can try?

Answer (score 0):

OH, I realized that the model was using an old baked texture stored in cache, that texture was baked with a different uv map. All i did to fix was save my new bake, disconnect the image texture from the render node, then reconnect the texture